# Set min date in custom date picker?

Tags: android

The problem is i am not able to set min day and month in date picker.
Because the days are added via a for loop and same as for month.

There is class called WheelDayPicker.java you can find the code to add day to picker and same as for month WheelMonthPicker.java class.

code to add the day in picker is: in WheelDayPicker.java

```
int days = mCalendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
List<Integer> data = DAYS.get(days);
if (null == data) {
data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
data.add(i);
DAYS.put(days, data);
}
```

and to add month is: in WheelMonthPicker.java

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
data.add(i);
```

Then how we can set min day and month in this?

Let say today date is 5th April 2017 so I want to hide all date above 5th April in the wheel.
above means 4rd April, 3nd April and so on.

You can see code on this link:-
[Custom Date Picker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to handle native `DatePickerDialog`

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog dialog;
dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, 0, onDateChangedListener, year, month, day);
dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "", dialog);
dialog.show();
```